# MySqldb and CGI are not working together

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, cgi

I am  using 2.7.8 on windows.I am getting nervous over the reason why this is happening and search a lot for it. Like i placed the cgi code 1st and checked it is working fine but when i just place `import MySQLdb` it does not execute and page shows `server error`.

here is the code without `import MySqldb` prints successfully:

file name: `cgisql.py`

```
#!C:\Python27\python
# Import modules for CGI handling 

import cgi


# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

[image]

with import MySqldb

```
#!C:\Python27\python
# Import modules for CGI handling 

import cgi
import MySQLdb

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

output on Page:

[image]

Sorry for longer description bcz i am facing some big problem and i honestly do nt know whats this mystery is.......

Comment: You should check the log first.

Comment: Do you actually have `MySQLdb` installed? Also [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) on how to enable errors so you can see what goes wrong. And please, if no one has replied for 30 minutes then don't leave comments. It will not make people reply faster, and only serves to make you come off presumptuous and pushy.

Comment: i wrote on console : import MySQLdb and it is showing no error

Comment: this is what i am getting: http://tinypic.com/r/15fmaop/9

Answer (score -1):

Finally i found the solution: 
just add :

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

to check the error.

Error appears:

[image]

So final solution:
add

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
```

This will 100% resolve the problem.....
Also thanks to Carpetsmoker